# Powershell Get-Content -> Foreach-Object -> -replace ->Out-File is adding a char (0x00) to the start of every file

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a function that performs a regex replace in a file. The problem is that that it adds a character (0x00) to the start of every file it touches (even the ones that it doesn't find a match for!). Since I am editing **csproj** files, MSBuild gives me this error:

```
error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 2, position 1.
```

Here is my function:

```
function fileStringRegExReplace ([string] $fileToChange, [string] $oldString, [string] $newString) {
    echo "f" | xcopy "$fileToChange" "$fileToChange.og.cs" /Y /Q

    $file = Get-Content "$fileToChange.og.cs" | 
        Foreach-Object {
            $_ -replace $oldString, $newString
        } |
        Out-File "$fileToChange"

    Remove-Item "$fileToChange.og.cs"
}
```

How can I replace the lines I want and not change any other part of the file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like it's writing a BOM at the beginning of the file.  You can set the encoding to ASCII (which has no BOM) using the `-Encoding ASCII` parameter on `out-file`.

Comment: for reasons unbeknownst to me `Set-Content` makes ASCII files by default and `Out-File` creates UCS-2 little endian files. [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655788/powershell-set-content-and-out-file-what-is-the-difference). I created a [`Get-FileEncoding`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121579/powershell-out-file-prevent-encoding-changes) function that attempts to determine what the source file encoding is  so that it can be used with the `-Encoding` parameter with `Set-Content` and `Out-File` which is useful for file updating like this.

Comment: I'm still also getting the issue after changing to Set-Content or using Out-File -Encoding ASCII.  I'm also replacing text in the csproj file.

Comment: have a solution, posting now.

Answer (score 2):

The default encoding of [Out-File](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849882.aspx) is `Unicode`, which is Windows-speak for **UTF-16**. When only writing characters from the ASCII set, UTF-16 basically has the effect of adding a `0x00` byte in front of each character. This explains why visual studio is complaining about `0x00` bytes.

The XML of the csproj files which you are trying to modify declare themselves to be **UTF-8**, so use the `-Encoding UTF8` option in Out-File.

Do not use the ASCII encoding, this will cause problems as soon as the csproj file gets a non-ASCII character in it.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue, after using a `ForEach` to replace the text, I ran into issues.

For my solution, I just wanted to find the last `</Target>` and add append another `<Target></Target>`.

I tried the approach and the file size doubled for some reason, and failing on the `0x00` error at `Line: 2, Position: 1` as well.

I must credit @Matt on this solution, as I probably wouldn't have figured out the regex on my own: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28437855/740575

This allowed me to elegantly not use the `ForEach` approach.  You should find your answer somewhere in this solution.

```powershell
$replaceVar = "<Target> ... </Target" ;
# NOTE: -Raw will read the entire file in as a string, without doing that
#       everything gets read in as an array of lines
$file = Get-Content file.csproj -Raw ;
$newFile = $file -replace "(?s)(.*)</Target>(.*)", "$1$replaceVar$2" ;

# csproj is UTF8
$newFile | Out-File -Encoding UTF8 "new.csproj" ;
```

Solution works within Visual Studio and `msbuild.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing out-file with set-content.