# Replacing last occurrence of substring in string

Tags: powershell, replace

How can you replace the *last* occurrence of a substring in a string?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Regular Expressions can also perform this task. Here is an example of one that would work. It will replace the last occurrence of "Aquarius" with "Bumblebee Joe"

```
$text = "This is the dawning of the age of Aquarius. The age of Aquarius, Aquarius, Aquarius, Aquarius, Aquarius"
$text -replace "(.*)Aquarius(.*)", '$1Bumblebee Joe$2'
This is the dawning of the age of Aquarius. The age of Aquarius, Aquarius, Aquarius, Aquarius, Bumblebee Joe
```

The greedy quantifier ensure that it take everything it can up until the last match of `Aquarius`. The `$1` and `$2` represent the data before and after that match.

If you are using a variable for the replacement you need to use double quotes and escape the `$` for the regex replacements so PowerShell does not try to treat them as a variable

```
$replace = "Bumblebee Joe"
$text -replace "(.*)Aquarius(.*)", "`$1$replace`$2"
```

Comment: It seems to work only with the replacement string being a literal.

Comment: That is only the case since it is enclosed in single quotes. I can update the answer to account for this.

Comment: Hmm, didn't seem to work for a multi-line string for some reason.  It ended up replacing all instances still.

Comment: @sonjz if the string is multiline then you could use single line mode. `"(?s)(.*)Aquarius(.*)", '$1Bumblebee Joe$2'`

Comment: Thanks @Matt, joy acheived!  I was having issues with a .NET .csproj file, works now, sharing my solution as csproj is finicky: $file = Get-Content file.csproj -Raw ; $newFile = $file -replace "(?s)(.*)XXX(.*)", "`$1$replaceVar`$2" ;  $newFile | Out-File -Encoding UTF8 "new.csproj" ;

Comment: How-to escape a number e.g. `$replace = "6th Aquarius"`? Results to `$16th Aquarius`…

Comment: Why do you need to escape the number?

Comment: Out of curiosity. Answered https://superuser.com/questions/1215093 however I'd like apply your approach…

Comment: @JosefZ "Escape" the `6` by escaping the capture id instead ``"`${1}6th..."``. @Matt, the number `6` needs to be escaped because it is not supposed to be part of identifying a capture group in the result of the regex, but the string expansion `""` is treating it thus.

Comment: Does anyone have qualms about using `\Z` for multiline strings. I've seen it elsewhere, and used it too, but I'm not sure if it's better than using `(?s)`.

Comment: @Matt how do I format the command to use a regex in place of Aquarius between the two (.*) as the first parameter? I basically want to replace the last formatted date in the string, so I am trying to get something like: $text -replace "(.*)`'(19|20)\d\d[- /.]([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])'`(.*)", '$1`$CurrentDate`$2'

Answer (score 6):

[Using the exact same technique as I would in `C#`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14825949/replace-last-match-in-string):

```
function Replace-LastSubstring {
    param(
        [string]$str,
        [string]$substr,
        [string]$newstr
    )

    return $str.Remove(($lastIndex = $str.LastIndexOf($substr)),$substr.Length).Insert($lastIndex,$newstr)
}
```

Comment: what is `$newstr`? Don't you only need Original String and Substring the user is looking for?

Comment: OP needed to *replace* the substring, not just remove it

Answer (score 1):

print(str1[::-1].replace("xx","rr",1)[::-1])