# Powershell: Replace last occurence of a line in a file

Tags: regex, powershell, pattern-matching

Suppose we have a file foo.txt:

```
abc
abc
abc
```

And I want to turn it into:

```
abc
abc
HelloWorld
```

This command should work:

```
(gc foo.txt -Raw) -replace '(.*)abc', '$1HelloWorld' | Out-File foo.txt
```

Because I'm using -Raw switch, which reads the entire file instead of one line at a time. Then, the greedy pattern (.*) should match everything up to the last "abc" and replace it with "HelloWorld".

But it doesn't work. All 3 occurences of "abc" are replaced with "HelloWorld", as if "-replace" was processing the file one line at a time, despite the -Raw switch.

Why?

Comment: there is already an simular question.
Please check out this question solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28436651/replacing-last-occurrence-of-substring-in-string

Comment: Yes, I saw that post and that's where I borrowed the idea from. However, it's not working in my case and I'm trying to understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to include the single line mode modifier `(?s)` like so:

```
(gc foo.txt -Raw) -replace '(?s)(.*)abc', '$1HelloWorld' | Out-File foo.txt
```

Without it, the `.` will not match carriage returns and line feeds.

Comment: Thank you @Matt for fixing it to the correct operator.

Answer (score 0):

I'm breaking PS to multiple lines for sake of simplicity. I'm replacing `sed` with `TEMPOR`

Try:

```
$rx = '(?is)(.*)sed(.*)'           ## Search for last occurance of sed.
$replacement = '$1TEMPOR$2'        ## Replace sed with TEMPOR
(Get-Content -Path d:\data.txt -Raw) -ireplace $rx, $replacement | Out-File d:\test.txt
```

> Content of data.txt:

```
A nulla odio aptent metus, 
mattis mattis elementum iaculis, 
malesuada proin vestibulum suspendisse pellentesque wisi. 
Faucibus turpis a ac. Wisi eros sed sit nec sed, 
sed et fringilla vulputate mattis pretium, 
rutrum vitae vitae euismod erat eu. 
Ac feugiat sed elit, pellentesque amet dis, 
non lorem vero rutrum, vel eu sodales orci a, 
vestibulum ante consectetur. 
Dui wisi massa a ut seddictumst, 
ultricies sed metus, 
orci urna amet mauris nibh, leo nec fusce.
```

> Output of test.txt:

```
A nulla odio aptent metus, 
mattis mattis elementum iaculis, 
malesuada proin vestibulum suspendisse pellentesque wisi. 
Faucibus turpis a ac. Wisi eros sed sit nec sed, 
sed et fringilla vulputate mattis pretium, 
rutrum vitae vitae euismod erat eu. 
Ac feugiat sed elit, pellentesque amet dis, 
non lorem vero rutrum, vel eu sodales orci a, 
vestibulum ante consectetur. 
Dui wisi massa a ut seddictumst, 
ultricies TEMPOR metus, 
orci urna amet mauris nibh, leo nec fusce.
```

Hopefully it answers your question.

Answer (score -1):

This is the right way to do it as you tried:

```
(Get-Content -Path C:\temp\test.txt -Raw) -replace '(.*)abc$', 'HelloWorld' | Out-File C:\temp\test.txt
```

And this is another way to do it:

```
$lines = Get-Content -Path C:\temp\test.txt
$last = $lines.Length - 1
$lines[$last] = "testtest"
Set-Content -Path C:\temp\test.txt -Value $lines
```